# Pulling a list of vendors and displaying them into columns JSP Functions

Tags: java, function, jsp

I am getting a list of names and I would like to display them into (3) columns. Whats would be the best way to do this using a jsp function?

List:

```
apples
oranges
cherries
limes
pineapples
grapefruits
coconuts
watermelons
grapes
bananas
pears
peaches
```

Expected Output -

```
Column 1 - apples, oranges, cherries, and limes /
Column 2 - pineapples, grapefruits, coconuts, and watermelons /
Column 3 - grapes, bananas, pears, peaches
```

1. Lets say that I wanted to specify how many rows are in each column, what would be the best way to do this using a jsp function?
2. Another scenario would be, if there is a list of 13 items and you divide that by the number of columns (3), you would get 4.333333333..

What function example could I used to get 6 in the first column, 6 in the second column and 1 in the 3rd column?

Any thoughts or comments I would really be grateful for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your collection, when 6 rows added add a new column, you could use nested tables, but div's are preferred.

```
<c:forEach varStatus="count" var="fruit" items="${fruits}">
...
  <c:when test=${count.index % 6 == 0}> //when loop count is multiple of six
  ... // create your column structure, be it, td, table or div
  </c:when>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hi NimChimpsky, I tried your way and it looks like it is skipping 6 items and returning the next item after the 6. Example:(0)apples
(1)oranges
(2)cherries
(3)limes
(4)pineapples
(5)grapefruits
(6)coconuts
(7)watermelons
(8)grapes
(9)bananas
(10)pears
(11)peaches, So now I only get 1 column and inside that column its shows, (0)apples,(5)grapefruits,(10)pears instead all the items in the column. I was also expecting it to build out 2 columns. I don't understand what was done. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I showed you how to create columns based on how many iterations using modulus, I also showed you how to loop a list etc. Show the code you are using and the desired result.